# No suitable driver found for jdbc:oacle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a login page for my college project. I need help to solve the error

[image]

Please help me to find faults. As you can see in the image the output frame is running successfully after entering the username and password click on the login button it shows the error in cmd, nothing happens simply a bunch of errors.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    ImageIcon icon;
    Dimension dimension;
    ImageIcon img;
    JLabel imglab;
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    JTextField usern;
    JPasswordField pass;

    Login() {
        dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - 450) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - 450) / 2);
        setLocation(x, y);
        icon = new ImageIcon("image/login.png");
        setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(600, 338);
        setTitle("Administrator login");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("Login");
        button.setBounds(250, 210, 80, 30);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Close");
        button1.setBounds(400, 210, 80, 30);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);
        add(button1);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Username");
        label1.setBounds(250, 90, 80, 30);
        label1.setFont(new Font("Son Gothic", Font.BOLD, 16));
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Password");
        label2.setBounds(250, 150, 80, 30);
        label2.setFont(new Font("Son Gothic", Font.BOLD, 16));
        add(label1);
        add(label2);
        usern = new JTextField();
        usern.setBounds(350, 90, 170, 30);
        usern.setFont(new Font("Son Gothic", Font.BOLD, 16));
        pass = new JPasswordField();
        pass.setEchoChar('*');
        pass.setBounds(350, 150, 170, 30);
        pass.setFont(new Font("Son Gothic", Font.BOLD, 16));
        add(usern);
        add(pass);
        img = new ImageIcon("image/LoginBack1.jpg");
        imglab = new JLabel(img);
        imglab.setSize(600, 337);
        add(imglab);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String str = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (str.equals("Login")) {
            try {

                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oacle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "system", "amanp");
                String sql = "select * from UserLogin where Usern='" + usern.getText() + "' and Userp='" + pass.getText() + "'";
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successfull");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username/Password");
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Login l = new Login();
        l.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your JDBC connection URL - it should be `oracle` not `oacle`.

Comment: Thank u so much there is one more thing that i have to ask when i compile my java file it shows "Note: Login.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details." what that means and how to fix it

Comment: Regarding `xlint`, take a look at [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+xlint).